# Get following sibling on android using Appium

Tags: java, appium

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='a1492']/../following-sibling::android.view.ViewGroup").click();
```

**This does not work. Am I missing anything?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`@text` is looking for an attribute `text`. If you're actually after the text content, it's `[text()='a1492']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, this will solve your problem:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.ViewGroup[preceding-sibling::android.view.ViewGroup/*[@text='a1492']]").click();
```